# Lubuntu 13.10 selected LX games desktop now can't login

Tags: lubuntu

I logged out of my normal desktop and selected LX games from the dropdown list and logged back in. This led me to a black screen and now I can't see the login screen in order to change back to my normal desktop. On startup the machine boots normally, the lubuntu splash screen shows up, then it goes to a black screen with nothing on it - not even a mouse cursor. I can bring up a terminal using ctrl+alt+F2.
Is there a way via terminal to change my desktop environment back to its previous state?
Or alternatively, is there a file I can edit where my preferred desktop is stored? (The machine is dual-booted so I can access the Lubuntu files from LXLE which is installed on a second partition).  The machine in question is a Toshiba A200 laptop.
UPDATE: I was unable to find a satisfactory way around this so have re-installed the OS.
Has anyone else been adventurous enough to select the lx games desktop and if so did they have any problems?

Answer (score 0):

I also selected LX Games session and could not see any UI after that. This is what worked for me:
I edited the file /etc/lightdm/lightdm.conf

[SeatDefaults]
autologin-guest=true --> I set this var to true
autologin-user=user_name
autologin-user-timeout=0
autologin-session=lightdm-autologin
greeter-session=lightdm-gtk-greeter
user-session=Lubuntu

After this change I restarted my computer.

I don't know if this is the correct way to solve it, but at least I was able to logout and select back the Lubuntu session, and reset the autologin-guest var to false again.
This link was also helpful for me: https://wiki.ubuntu.com/LightDM

Note: I activated the autologin option when I installed Lubuntu.

Answer (score -2):

Press the combination CTRL-ALT-F1 
login with your root password
type top to see the current active programs running
then type killall lxsession

Comment: Please add more details to your answer, proper formatting will also improve legibility.